# Make images layed out as 'inline-block' have on-hover titles on the bottom

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I'm developing an image gallery and want to display titles on the bottom of an image in the following way:

- Image is shown without any text by default
- When hovering mouse over image, a (possibly truncated) title appears on the bottom on a dark-gray semi-transparent background
- Preferably, my HTML stays as is; most importantly the images remain as 'display: inline-block' as that's how they are needed for the layout.
- (Optional) When hovering over the title (if it was truncated) it is expanded fully
- (Optional) Titles can contain links / whole image is a link

Please see a graphical explanation:
[image: Graphical Explanation]

This is somewhat similar to how http://www.flickr.com/explore and many other sites do it.

Here is what I have so far (not too much, actually, as it renders the title in the vertical middle, not on the bottom):

```css
.image-block {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.container { /* testing only */
    width: 1555px;
    overflow: scroll;
}



.hover-me {
   position: relative;

}

.hover-me img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display: block;
}

.hover-me:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: rgba(128,128,128,.5);
    transition: all .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}

.hover-me .caption {
    display: block;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -10px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #fff;
}

.hover-me:hover:after , .hover-me:hover .caption {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span  class="image-block hover-me ng-scope" style="padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; height: 257px; width: 269px;">
            <img class="hovertext" width="269" height="257" src="http://i.imgur.com/zOEilgll.jpg">
           <span class="caption">This is a longish text of what looks like a camel; really quote a long long long long long long long long long long long long text</span>
    </span><span  class="image-block hover-me ng-scope" style="padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; height: 257px; width: 385px;">
            <img class="hovertext" width="385" height="257" src="http://i.imgur.com/jj1dY0sl.jpg">
           <span class="caption">Well this is quite a pretty picture too</span>
    </span><span  class="image-block hover-me ng-scope" style="padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px; height: 257px; width: 396px;">
            <img class="hovertext" width="396" height="257" src="http://i.imgur.com/yVlWIc0l.jpg">
           <span class="caption">Omg what is this a black and white picture</span>
    </span><span  class="image-block hover-me ng-scope" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 5px; height: 257px; width: 456px;">
            <img class="hovertext" width="456" height="257" src="http://i.imgur.com/roRmFJWl.jpg">
           <span class="caption">This is just an ordinary truck, I think... maybe; but the discription is really quite long</span>
    </span><span  class="image-block hover-me ng-scope" style="padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; height: 289px; width: 433px;">
            <img class="hovertext" width="433" height="289" src="http://i.imgur.com/yo2WhKFl.jpg">
           <span class="caption">A great quote frm a great explorer</span>
    </span>
    <span>More images follow...</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's pretty easy, you will need CSS Positioning here, wrap the element using `position: relative;` container... I made this from scratch, see if it's useful to you, if you need any modifications, just ping me..

Explanation: First am making the `.wrap` element `position: relative;` just to make sure the nested `absolute` positioned `span` stays relative to the container.

In the next selector i.e `.wrap span` am using `position: absolute;` for `span` with a negative margin, which is deliberately overflown, so that it hides.

Coming to next selector i.e `.wrap:hover span` will show the first line of the `span` element.

And the last selector which is `.wrap:hover span:hover` will show the rest of the text.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ypSK/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ypSK/2/) <sup>[1] Fixed `white-space` at the bottom</sup>

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -70px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.wrap:hover span {
    bottom: -40px;
}

.wrap:hover span:hover {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

---

```
.wrap img {
    display: block;
}
```

<sup>[1] Add this to your code to fix the `white-space` at the bottom of the image.</sup>

> Note: The dimensions are fixed, if you think the text for each
>   thumbnail may vary to a great extent, than I will recommend you to use
>   jQuery and set the `height` of the `span` elements accordingly.

Comment: For some strange reason it appears to work on first image but not on others: http://jsfiddle.net/johnmurdoch/8EKJG/

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work with short text (nothing is displayed): http://jsfiddle.net/johnmurdoch/4LetQ/

Comment: Well that’s obviously because the small text is not high enough to be displayed when positioned only `-40px` from the bottom …

Comment: @JohnM That's why I've stated something in the note at the end of my answer :) http://jsfiddle.net/4LetQ/2/