# click on a text which is displayed when an image is hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have [*this jsfiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/w95C8/1/).

- I want to display a text when and image is hovered (with `.animate`).
- When the text is displayed and then hovered, users can click on it.
- When both of text and image are not hovered, text fade out.
- Users can't hover the text without hover the image first.

Can someone help me to do that ?

Here is what I did :

html :

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="blabla.jpg" />
    <p id="p1"> click here ! </p>
</div>
```

jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                                        // on img hover
    $("img").hover(function() {
        $(this).next().animate({            // Change p1 style
            'opacity': '1',
            top: "+=10px"},
        200);
                                        // Non hovered   
    }, function() {
        $(this).next().animate({           // Restore p1 style
            'opacity': '0',
            top: "-=10px"},
        200);
    });


    $('#p1').hover(function() {    // On p1 hover
        $(this).next().css({          // change p1 style
            'opacity': '1',
            top: "-51px"});
    }, function() {                // Non hovered
        $(this).next().css({
            'opacity': '0',          // restore p1 style
            top: "-41px"});
    });

});
```

simple css:

```
#container{
    position:relative;
    top: 20px;
    left:20px;
    width:110px;
    height:110px;
}

#p1{
    position:relative;
    color:white;
    width:110px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:-55px;
    left:50%;
    background-color: navy;
    height:20px;
    opacity:0;
    top: -129px;
}
```

Comment: jsfiddle link updated.. the old one was an old version

Comment: I'd move the hover logic up to your container element, just make it the same dimensions as the image.  That way the text wont disappear when you  mouse over it.

Comment: How about achieving that with [CSS Only](http://jsfiddle.net/4ypSK/2/)?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I shared only JS Fiddle link, if you want to refer my answer for the same, [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809336/make-images-layed-out-as-inline-block-have-on-hover-titles-on-the-bottom/21809439#21809439)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this with CSS only. Much easier to use.

```css
.box{
  background:red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
}

.box:hover a{
  top:10px;
  opacity:1;
}

a{
    -webkit-transition:all .4s;
    -moz-transition:all .4s;
    -o-transition:all .4s;
    -ms-transition:all .4s;
    transition:all .4s;
  background:blue;
  color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  text-align:center;
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="http://google.co.uk">Click Me!</a>
</div>
```

Links to above code on:
[<kbd>CodePen</kbd>](http://codepen.io/BeatAlex/pen/vwEdf) [<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/3gPcp/)

Have a look at [Mr. Alien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939981/click-on-a-text-which-is-displayed-when-an-image-is-hovered#comment33236035_21939981)'s comment for a more advanced version of this.